# sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

Tags: 12.04

I am using dell 3542, installing the softwares while giving some permission issue as below. I come to know that sudo command is not working. So i have executed 2nd point but no use.

1)

```
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

2)

```
 pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

Error getting  authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct
```

3) When i exeute ls command it is showing like this

```
ls -l /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 185288 Jun  1  2012 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

How can I fix this issue. Any help is appreciated

Comment: sodoers.so is owned by root. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i cannt able to execute any commands with sudo, also all my options went to readonly. Please help me to fix this issue !!!!

Comment: It should look like this: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 329824 Feb 10  2014 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` on 14.04. I'll check 12.04 when I get the chance.

Comment: I think this is more interesting: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct

Comment: pls help me out !!!!!!!